# How get the birthday list of yesterday, today and tomorrow in mysql from the date of birth?

Tags: mysql

This is the list of date of birth. Now I need to get the ID or each person whose birthday is today, or tomorrow or yesterday.

I have been trying a lot but not getting the right result. Please comment with the proper demo so that it will help me to understand.

My DB structure is:

```
ID           DOB
 1          2001-10-15
 2          2002-09-13
 3          2002-09-11
 4          2003-05-09
 5          2006-09-12
```

lets take an ex: Today is 11-09-2015. So I want the result like

```
ID           DOB          DAY
 5          2002-09-12   Today
 3          2002-09-11   Yesterday
 2          2006-09-13   Tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below query

```
SELECT DOB,
       IF (DAY(DOB)=DAY(NOW())
           AND MONTH(DOB)=MONTH(NOW()),
                          'TODAY',
                          IF (DAY(DOB) =DAY(ADDDATE(NOW(),-1))
                              AND MONTH(DOB)=MONTH(ADDDATE(NOW(),-1)),
                                             'Yesterday',
                                             IF (DAY(DOB) =DAY(ADDDATE(NOW(),+1))
                                                 AND MONTH(DOB)=MONTH(ADDDATE(NOW(),+1)),
                                                                'Tomorrow',
                                                                'Future') ) )
FROM tmp;
```

Output

2015-09-10 Yesterday

2015-09-11 TODAY

2015-09-12 Tomorrow

2015-09-13 Future

Comment: My code is this - it gives me the same please check it out and reply me is this acceptable too - 

SELECT
id,school_id,
dob,
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') + IF(
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1, '%m%d'), 1, 0) AS new_age, DATEDIFF(dob + INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()-1) - YEAR(dob) + IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1, '%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m%d'), 1, 0) YEAR,
CURDATE()) AS days_to_birthday
FROM se_users where school_id = 970
HAVING days_to_birthday IN (-1,0,1) ORDER BY days_to_birthday ASC

Comment: Glad it worked!,Seems you are trying based on INTERVAL , and that should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 <?php

$today=date('Y-m-d');
$yesterday=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$tomorrow=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 days"));


$sql=mysql_query("select id from tablename where dob='$today' OR   dob='$yesterday' OR dob='$tomorrow'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

  echo $row;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the date of birth for different users is different. i need to compare the month and days.